# Configuring Proxy Details to connect to Snowflake

Tags: python, apache-spark, proxy, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to see if I can use Snowflake connector for spark to connect to snowflake from my python/notebook. Below is what I am using for this connection.

Spark version - 2.3

Snowflake JDBC  - snowflake-jdbc-3.9.2.jar

Snowflake Connector - spark-snowflake_2.11-2.4.14-spark_2.3.jar

However I am behind a corporate proxy and will need to specify proxy settings some where. Not sure how can achieve the same.

Ideally if I am using JDBC connection I would specify something like this.

> jdbc:snowflake://myaccount.snowflakecomputing.com/?warehouse=mywh&role=myrole&**useProxy=true&proxyHost=myproxy&proxyPort=80**

But now that I am using a native connector to snowflake, as per the documentation on snowflake website, options needs to be set as below but there is no mention of proxy variables. Would appreciate if any one has inputs for me here.

## Set options below

```
 sfOptions = {
  "sfURL" : "<account_name>.snowflakecomputing.com",
  "sfAccount" : "<account_name>",
  "sfUser" : "<user_name>",
  "sfPassword" : "<password>",
  "sfDatabase" : "<database>",
  "sfSchema" : "<schema>",
  "sfWarehouse" : "<warehouse>",
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Besides in the connection sting, there are other options available for configuring a proxy with the Snowflake JDBC driver.  Have you seen the documentation here?
https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/jdbc-configure.html#connecting-using-a-proxy-server

Comment: yes . I did try all of those. I tried to pass parameters to JVM as below as I am running spark in client mode . But no luck                                                                                                   `--driver-java-options '-Dhttp.useProxy=true -Dhttps.proxyHost=myproxy.com -Dhttp.proxyHost=8080 -Dhttps.proxyPort=myproxy.com -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080'                --driver-class-path /path/to/spark-snowflake_2.11-2.4.14-spark_2.3.jar:/path/to/snowflake-jdbc-3.9.2.jar --jars /path/to/snowflake-jdbc-3.9.2.jar,/path/to/spark-snowflake_2.11-2.4.14-spark_2.3.jar pyspark-shell`

Comment: Are you getting an error when trying to to set them? Are they not getting passed?  What are you seeing?  You could also test setting the proxy with a different application connecting to Snowflake and make sure the values are taking.

Answer (score 0):

After many unsuccessful attempts, finally i am able figure this out.

a. Choose the right snowflake connector for your spark/scala (Refer to : https://github.com/harithatavarthy/Spark-Snowflake/blob/master/sparkSession_toSnowflake.ipynb)

b. Pass the proxy server details as inputs to extraJavaOptions..In client mode, this config must not be set through the SparkConf directly in your application, because the driver JVM has already started at that point.

```
    os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS']="--driver-class-path /path/to/snowflake-jdbc- 
    3.6.12.jar:/path/to/spark-snowflake_2.11-2.4.8.jar --conf 
    'spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Dhttp.useProxy=true -Dhttps.useProxy=true - 
    Dhttp.proxyHost=proxy.server.com -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080 - 
    Dhttps.proxyHost=proxy.server.com -Dhttps.proxyPort=8080' --conf 
   'spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Dhttp.useProxy=true -Dhttps.useProxy=true - 
    Dhttp.proxyHost=proxy.server.com -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080 - 
    Dhttps.proxyHost=proxy.server.com -Dhttps.proxyPort=8080' --jars 
    /path/to/snowflake-jdbc-3.6.12.jar,/path/to/spark-snowflake_2.11-2.4.8.jar 
    pyspark-shell"
```