# VSCode/Snowflake: How to connect to Snowflake DB via proxy?

Tags: sql, visual-studio-code, proxy, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

This is an extension to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68183272/vscode-snowflake-how-to-connect-to-snowflake-db-via-single-sign-on) issue. I'm trying to connect to a snowflake database using VSCode, it seems like there are no options to connect via a proxy? Where can I input my proxy details?

Comment: Have you tried the options from this post?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58946325/configuring-proxy-details-to-connect-to-snowflake